# Kotlin Exposed get number of rows updated

Tags: kotlin, ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am updating some table and I need to check if the update was successful. I am doing this

```
MyTable.update({ MyTable.name eq "abcd" }) {
  it[col1] = "col1 value"
}
```

In the current state, if I try to update some value that does not exist in DB, even then the call succeeds (probably saying zero rows updated).

How do I know if there was actually a row to be updated or how do I get the number of rows updated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty simple. The output of `update` call returns the count.

```
val numRowsUpdated = MyTable.update({ MyTable.name eq "abcd" }) {
  it[col1] = "col1 value"
}
```

`numRowsUpdated` will have the count.